# How to remove the array elements from an array only if the string has a substring named abc.com in Mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone help me with a query on how to remove strings from an array in mongodb only if the string has a substring "abc.com"

Current result in a collection :

```
{
 _id: '1',
users: ['1@abc.com', '2@abc.com', '3@def.com']
}
{
 _id: '2',
users: ['1@abc.com', '2@def.com', '3@def.com']
}
```

Expected Result :

```
{
     _id: '1',
    users: ['3@def.com']
}
{
     _id: '2',
    users: ['2@def.com', '3@def.com']
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a **read-only** query, you can use the `$filter` operator to filter the value with doesn't match the domain address via `$not` and `$regexMatch` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      users: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$users",
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $regexMatch: {
                input: "$$this",
                regex: "(?:@abc\\.com)$"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo (Read-only) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GK3XbuyVGVB)

---

For **updating** the document(s), you need to use the `$pull` operator to remove the value from the array if matches the regex.

```
db.collection.update({
  users: {
    $regex: "(?:@abc\\.com)$"
  }
},
{
  $pull: {
    users: {
      $regex: "(?:@abc\\.com)$"
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Demo (Update) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k_H1zKME9yd)

Comment: can you tell me how the above regex will work briefly?

Comment: Ya sure, basically the regex is aimed to match whether the respective string value ends with `@abc.com`, with `(?:)` representing a non-capturing group and `$` representing the end of string, which are the syntaxes in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work for you:

```
var str="abc.com"
db.find({users: { $in: [str] }},(err,objects)=>{

    if(err)return;
    if(objects.count() ==0) return;
    objects.map(obj=>{
        obj.users = obj.users.filter((name) => !name.includes(str));
        obj.save()
    })
})
```